# Delete stopwords from text file in C#

Tags: c#, stop-words

I read two text files : the first contains Arabic text , I split it. The second contains the stop-words.
I want to delete any stop-words (in the second file) from the first file, but I don't know how to do this:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"H:\\arabictext.txt", FileMode.Open);
StreamReader arab = new StreamReader(fs,Encoding.Default,true);
string artx = arab.ReadToEnd();
richTextBox1.Text = artx;
arab.Close();
char[] dele = {' ', ',', '.', '\t', ';','#','!' };

string[] words = richTextBox1.Text.Split(dele);

FileStream fsw = new FileStream("H:\\arab.txt", FileMode.Create);
StreamWriter arabw = new StreamWriter(fsw,Encoding.Default);

foreach (string s in words)
{
    arabw.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Comment: Put stopwords in a HashSet<String> "stopwords". Loop through "words", write anything that's not contained in "stopwords" to arabw.

Comment: How is the second file formatted? One stopword on each line?

Comment: How big are these files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for my question..
do you have a better solution?

```
        char[] dele = { ' ', ',', '.', '\t', ';', '#', '!' };
        using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@"H:\output.txt"))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("H:\\arabictext.txt",Encoding.Default,true))
            {
                string line;

                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    string[] stopWord = new string[] { "قد", "في", "بيت", "فواصل", "هي", "من","$","ُ","ِ","ُ","ّ","ٍ","ٌ","ْ","ً" };


                    foreach (string word in stopWord)
                    {

                        line = line.Replace(word, "");

                    }

                    tw.Write(line);


                }
            }
        }
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"H:\\output.txt", FileMode.Open);
        StreamReader arab = new StreamReader(fs,Encoding.Default,true);
        string artx = arab.ReadToEnd();
        arab.Close();
        string[] words = artx.Split(dele);

        FileStream fsw = new FileStream("H:\\result.txt", FileMode.Create);
        StreamWriter arabw = new StreamWriter(fsw,Encoding.Default);
        foreach (string s in words)
        {

         arabw.WriteLine(s);

        }
        arabw.Close();
        arab.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to find stop-words from the first file and remove those stop-words from the second file.

Here is my workaround:

1. Extract stop-words by split method from the first file
2. Iterate extracted words from the first file and replace them with `String.Empty` in the content of 2nd file.
3. Save the file

I simplified your code into the code below:

```
        // read file contents
        var fileContent1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("file1.txt");
        var fileContent2 = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("file2.txt");

        // extract stop-words from first file
        var words = fileContent1.Split(new char[] { ' ', ',', '.', '\t', ';', '#', '!' })
                                .Distinct();

        // rmeove stop words in file2
        foreach (var word in words)
            fileContent2.Replace(word, string.Empty);

        System.IO.File.WriteAllText("file2.txt", fileContent2);
```

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov True!